# Camel SFTP - Cannot change directory to '/'

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

I need to connect via SFTP to a server and I receive this error:

```
INFO  [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect]: **Connected to sftp://myserver.com:22**
INFO  [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.connectIfNecessary]: **Connected and logged in to: Endpoint[sftp://myserver.com:22//home/tomcat/directory?password=******]
INFO  [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations$JSchLogger.log]: JSCH -> **Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Read timed out**
INFO  [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations$JSchLogger.log]: JSCH -> **Disconnecting from myserver.com port 22**
WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.handleFailedWrite]: **Writing file failed with: Cannot change directory to: /**
```

I tried to use camel SFTP options `maximumReconnectAttempts=10`, `serverAliveInterval=60` and to change the camel version to **2.12.0** and then to **2.10.7** (versions where the issue is fixed), but none of these fixed my issue.
Seems to be a bug , but the weird thing is that **it is not reproduced every time** I try to connect to my server.

I appreciate any kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

I solved my issue after adding the camel SFTP option `disconnect=true`.

Comment: Worked for me as well. I had to also put the option `stepwise=false`. The failure was only on the second connection which generate the error, the first connection was always successful. Putting `disconnect=true` force to release the connection between two consecutive calls.

Comment: I also had to use stepwise=false, disconnect=true alone was not enough. using camel 2.18.1

Answer (score 1):

You have double slash, eg `//home/tomcat/directory` which indicates an absolute path.

Maybe try with, a single slash so its a relative path `sftp://myserver.com:22/home/tomcat/directory`

Comment: Well, I need to use the absolute path, because I want to connect to different machines. If I would use the relative path, I couldn't connect to the directory I need.

Comment: make sure you have permission to do so

Comment: I have all the permissions I need. Sometimes I am able to connect with success and the exception is not thrown, but sometimes I am not. Maybe I will use camel SCP..

Answer (score 1):

If that can help. I had the same problem, it was because there was no more disk space.

Answer (score 0):

For me, camel version 2.17.1 fixed the issue. My previous versions that had the problem was 2.15.3 and 2.15.4.