# How to resolve 'Cannot change directory to: /' while transferring a file from a Windows machine to an SFTP server using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, file-transfer

I have set up my code to transfer files between a Windows machine and an SFTP server (both to & fro) with the help of from().to() methods in Apache Camel.

During runtime, I am getting an error that goes "Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot change directory to: /".

I had initially ran into this error when transferring files from an SFTP server to my Windows local machine. After research, I inserted "stepwise=false" within the body of from() which seems to have fixed the issue for transfer in that particular direction specifically.

However, I get the same error when I try to transfer files in the reverse direction, i.e., from my local Windows machine to an SFTP server. Given below is the code snippet.

```
from("file:D://camel//folder1?noop=true")
.to("sftp://username@hostaddress//testfolder/?password=password&PreferredAuthentications=publickey,keyboard-interactive,password&autoCreate=true&stepwise=false&passiveMode=true&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true&disconnect=true");
```

I am posting the error logs here.

```
INFO: Connected to sftp://username@hostaddress:22
Jan 08, 2019 2:18:16 PM org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer handleFailedWrite
WARNING: Writing file failed with: Cannot change directory to: /
<Jan 8, 2019 2:18:16 PM IST> <Warning> <org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer> <BEA-000000> <Writing file failed with: Cannot change directory to: /> 
Jan 08, 2019 2:18:16 PM org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations$JSchLogger log
INFO: JSCH -> Disconnecting from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
Jan 08, 2019 2:18:16 PM org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion processStrategyRollback
WARNING: Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@142d263c for file: GenericFile[D:\camel\folder1\samplefile.txt]
<Jan 8, 2019 2:18:16 PM IST> <Warning> <org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion> <BEA-000000> <Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@142d263c for file: GenericFile[D:\camel\folder1\samplefile.txt]> 


Jan 08, 2019 2:18:16 PM org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger log
SEVERE: Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-CW072202-45306-1546937295106-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-CW072202-45306-1546937295106-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot change directory to: /

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [file://D:/camel/folder1?antInclude=samplefile.txt%2CTesdt.txt%2C&noop=] [       183]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [sftp://username@hostaddress//testfolder?password=xxxxxx&Pr] [       176]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
Id                  ID-CW072202-45306-1546937295106-0-2
ExchangePattern     InOnly
Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-CW072202-45306-1546937295106-0-1, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileAbsolutePath=D:\camel\folder1\samplefile.txt, CamelFileContentType=text/plain, CamelFileLastModified=1546937281742, CamelFileLength=6, CamelFileName=samplefile.txt, CamelFileNameConsumed=samplefile.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=samplefile.txt, CamelFileParent=D:\camel\folder1, CamelFilePath=D:\camel\folder1\samplefile.txt, CamelFileRelativePath=samplefile.txt, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
BodyType            org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile
Body                [Body is file based: GenericFile[D:\camel\folder1\samplefile.txt]]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot change directory to: /
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.doChangeDirectory(SftpOperations.java:542)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(SftpOperations.java:499)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.buildDirectory(SftpOperations.java:438)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:266)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.process(RemoteFileProducer.java:56)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:157)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:304)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:152)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:433)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: 3: Permission denied.
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2833)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2185)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:343)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.doChangeDirectory(SftpOperations.java:540)
... 25 more
```

I am not sure what is it that I am failing to see here. Would greatly appreciate some nudge in the right direction which might solve the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Camel SFTP - Cannot change directory to '/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524582/camel-sftp-cannot-change-directory-to)

Comment: This not working by changing "//home/tomcat/directory"  to 
    sftp://myserver.com:22/home/tomcat/directory , i also changed camel 2.18.1 . Here my SFTP server is windows machine